# Google My Business Api Formatting Posts Issues

Tags: google-my-business-api

I've been using the GMB Api but I still can't figure out how to format post through the Api or if its even possible. I tried sending raw HTML in the `summary` field but GMB renders it as a string. I searched the documentation but I can't find anything on how to properly format the post for example bold and italic sections. Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google My Business posts do not (currently) support any rich text formatting or markup. They are just plain text.